# Angular cli error when processing trigonometry function (cosine) on an SCSS transform - Undefined operation: "cos(_) times _px"

Tags: sass, transform, angular-cli, trigonometry

I am trying to implement an SCSS component into my AngularCLI project (from Codepen: https://codepen.io/lbebber/pen/LELBEo).

When I run the following SCSS transform, `transform:translate3d(cos(0.1)*115px,sin(0.1)*115px,0);`

**I get the following build error:**

**`Module build failed:
      transform:translate3d(cos(0.1)*115px, sin(0.1)*115px, 0);
                           ^
      Undefined operation: "cos(0.1) times 115px".`**

I read up on SASS/SCSS numeric conversions, but found this is not the issue - as I tried replicating this in the Codepen, and his code is working just fine, no flawed conversion logic.

I can only suspect this is an issue with my AngularCLI configuration, something isn't registering correctly, and *the cosine is being interpreted as a string instead of its numeric calculation*. When hardcoding the numbers for cosine/sine, I get a valid build and see the UI functioning as expected.

**Do I need to configure the AngularCLI project in a way that lets the SCSS process the numeric values for cosine/sine before stepping into the equation as a string?** If so, how?

Much appreciation for anyone that has the Angular-fu to figure out how to get this to work.

Comment: I think it’s because the CodePen example uses [Compass](http://compass-style.org/) which you don’t have/use. You could try to import [mathsass](https://github.com/terkel/mathsass), maybe everything already works after that.

Comment: @mzdr You sir, really are a magician! I had already been trying to use Compass to no avail, but mathsass did the trick! That said, even after I got it to work, I couldn't help but investigate further...according to [this discussion](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2115) compass support has been removed from CLI...it's now part of the webpack. On further research, I'm finding that the Autoprefixer preprocessing might be the preferred way. What do you think? Either way, I think you can mark it as an answer, since I have a working solution thanks to you :)

Comment: Hehe, I’m glad that it worked out! Regarding Compass, you’re right. They dropped it from the CLI but it’s not part of webpack and PostCSS + Autoprefixer is the current state of the art and way to go. If you need to adjust the target browsers for autoprefixer in your angular app check out the CLI [wiki](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-autoprefixer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As we have found out it’s because your CodePen example uses the [Compass Math Helpers](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/helpers/math/) functions which you don’t have/use.

You could instead for example import [mathsass](https://github.com/terkel/mathsass). It should cover the same amout of functionality.

Comment: Thanks friend. Looks like I'm on for a night of learning Autoprefixer, with mathsass in the back pocket